# How to use startsWith and str_length simultaneously with multiple prefixes in R

Tags: r, prefix, string-length, startswith

I would like to use startsWith and str_length to identify the entries in the endpt_ds$DX1 that have start with the strings in dx9 and have a prefix of length greater than or equal to 3. This is what I've tried, but it returns a dataframe of zero rows. I would like it to return a dataframe with the 1st, 4th and 5th rows of the original dataframe:

```
dx9 = c(as.character(8:10))
DX1 <- c("8001","7","80","992","1010","93","400")
ind <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
yrMonth_ds = as.data.frame(cbind(DX1,ind))
yrMonth_ds$DX1 <- as.character(yrMonth_ds$DX1)
yrMonth_ds_endpt <- yrMonth_ds[which(startsWith(yrMonth_ds$DX1,paste0(dx9,collapse="|")) & str_length(yrMonth_ds$DX1 > 3)),]
yrMonth_ds_endpt
```

I would really appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed! (I added a closing parenthesis to DX1)

Comment: Yes, I don't want it to return the 7th row.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I was checking your preivous example

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to check the number of characters with `nchar`, create a logical expression with that, in addition use `paste` on the 'dx9' by collapsing it to a single pattern string with `^` to specify the start of the string and check with 'DX1' using `grepl` to return the rows that pass with both logic

```
subset(yrMonth_ds, nchar(DX1) >=3  & 
     grepl(paste0("^(", paste(dx9, collapse="|"), ")"), DX1))
#    DX1 ind
#1 8001   0
#4  992   1
#5 1010   0
```

Comment: Hi @akrun.  Unfortunately this is not quite right because I don't want it to return any digit, just the ones in dx9.  I edited the example to include an entry that starts with a digit not in dx9 and is of length 3, so it should not be returned, but it is being returned by your answer.

Comment: @abra If it is not in 'dx9', why you want to return row 5.  It also starts with 10?

Comment: dx9 contains 10.
dx9 = c(as.character(8:10))
dx9 = c(8,9,10)
Therefore I want row 5 returned

Comment: @abra  Yes, and row 5 and row 7 also have 10 as starting prefix.  My point is that if you are deleting 7, why can't 5

Comment: Because of what dx9 stands for, I need to be able to return 8001, 992 and 1010.  I need it to not return 400 because 4 is not contained within dx9

Comment: @abra Okay, got it.  Can you check now

Comment: Now it's perfect.  Thank you!